# How to find out coefficient $b_1$ in summation $\sin n\theta=\sum_{r=0}^{n} b_r \sin^r\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

> Let $n$ be a odd integer. If 
>   $$\sin  n\theta=\sum_{r=0}^{n} b_r \sin^r\theta$$
>   for every value of $\theta$. I have to find $b_1$.

I don't know how to start this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's $n$. First, consider this complex identity:

$$e^{in\theta}=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n$$

$$e^{in\theta}=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)$$

By the binomial development:

$$(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=\cos^n\theta+in\cos^{n-1}\theta\sin\theta+(powers\,of\,\sin\theta>1)=$$

Because $n$ odd and $n-1$ even:

$$\cos^n\theta+in(\cos^2\theta)^{(n-1)/2}\sin\theta+(powers\,of\,\sin\theta>1)=$$

$$\cos^n\theta+in(1-\sin^2\theta)^{(n-1)/2}\sin\theta+(powers\,of\,\sin\theta>1)=$$

$$\cos^n\theta+in\sin\theta+(powers\,of\,\sin\theta>1)$$

Now:

$$\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)=\cos^n\theta+in\sin\theta+(powers\,of\,\sin\theta>1)$$

Taking the imaginary part:

$$\sin(n\theta)=n\sin\theta+ (powers\,of\,\sin\theta>1)$$

And it's done with the bonus of $b_0=0$

Comment: where did $(1-sin^2 \theta)$ vanish from second step towards third?

Comment: Again using the power, now $(n-1)/2$, of a binomy, the second term is $-((n-1)/2)\sin^{2}\theta$. The next ones have even greater powers of $\sin\theta$. Then, after multiplying by $\sin\theta$, all of them but the first are assimilated to the "tail" of powers of $\sin\theta$ greater than one.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin  n\theta=\sum_{r=0}^{n} b_r \sin^r\theta=b_0+b_1\sin \theta+\sum_{r=2}^{n} b_r \sin^r\theta$$
by differentiation of this equivalency we have
$$n\cos n\theta=b_1\cos \theta+\sum_{r=2}^{n} b_r r\sin^{r-1}\theta\cos\theta$$
set $\theta=2\pi$ you take
$$\color{blue}{b_1=n}$$